# Re-seeding cuRAND host API

Tags: random, cuda

Is it possible to re-seed the cuRAND host API RNG?

I have found that if I create, allocate and generate two separate instances of the host API RNG with the same seed they produce the exact same sequence of numbers as expected.

However, if I create one instance, allocate, seed and generate a sequence of numbers, and then call curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed() again with the same seed, generate new numbers they are a different sequence. I would expect them to be reset to the same sequence again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the seed won't reset the sequence. Try using [`curandSetGeneratorOffset()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/group__HOST.html#group__HOST_1gb21ba987f85486e552797206451b0939)

Here's a worked example (derived from the host API example [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/host-api-overview.html#host-api-example)):

```
$ cat t85.cu
/* * This program uses the host CURAND API to generate 100 * pseudorandom floats. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=cudaSuccess) { \
 printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
 return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)
#define CURAND_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
 printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
 return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  size_t n = 10;
  size_t i;
  curandGenerator_t gen;
  float *devData, *hostData; /* Allocate n floats on host */
  hostData = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float)); /* Allocate n floats on device */
  CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devData, n*sizeof(float))); /* Create pseudo-random number generator */
  CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT)); /* Set seed */
  CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL)); /* Generate n floats on device */
  CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n)); /* Copy device memory to host */
  CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); /* Show result */
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { printf("%1.4f ", hostData[i]); }
  printf("\n");
  CURAND_CALL(curandSetGeneratorOffset(gen, 0)); /* Copy device memory to host */
  CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n)); /* Copy device memory to host */
  CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); /* Show result */
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { printf("%1.4f ", hostData[i]); }
  printf("\n");

   /* Cleanup */
  CURAND_CALL(curandDestroyGenerator(gen));
  CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devData));
  free(hostData);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t85 t85.cu -lcurand
$ ./t85
0.1455 0.8202 0.5504 0.2948 0.9147 0.8690 0.3219 0.7829 0.0113 0.2855
0.1455 0.8202 0.5504 0.2948 0.9147 0.8690 0.3219 0.7829 0.0113 0.2855
$
```